# ¿Cómo asigno el valor a una variable en base al cálculo de otra, con JS?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Necesito que cuando alguien en un **input** escriba arriba o igual del número 3, en otro input me cargue el dato que trabajo 3 horas dobles, voy a entrar más en contexto y decir lo que son mis condicionales.

Por ejemplo, yo voy a trabajar 5 horas, entonces en mi input yo pondré el dato "5" en otro input llamado "dobles" debería cargarme el dato "3" pues son 3 horas dobles que trabajo y otro input llamado "triples" me marque "2" pues es el resto de las horas.

Las condicionales aquí son: las primeras 3 siempre se irán al campo **"DOBLES"** y el restante al otro input llamado **"TRIPLES"**

Tengo otra condicional que es "Cuando las horas dobles ya sean 9, el resto de horas se irán a las horas triples" pero creo que esto lo quiero empezar a realizar cuando ya tenga la primera parte.

Aquí está la forma en que debería de verse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Acá agrego la estructura de mi tabla:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function HorasTD() {
    var ValInpHoras = $("input#horas").val();

    if (ValInpHoras >= 3) {
        $("#InputDobles").val(3);
    }

    var ValInpTriples =  ValInpHoras - 3;
    $("#InputTriples").val(ValInpTriples);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="0" class="form-control" name="horas" id="horas" onChange="HorasTD();"/>

<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="InputDobles" id="InputDobles" readonly=""/>

<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="InputTriples" id="InputTriples" readonly=""/>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega la estructura de tu tabla como texto, para mejor legibilidad. Además, ¿qué ya has intentado? agrega un [repro]

Comment: Hasta el momento pues lo mas basico, lo dejo aca. https://jsfiddle.net/zvbpntg1/

Comment: Para que tu código esté rápidamente a la vista, puedes editar tu pregunta agregando un [snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet) de lo que tienes en el fiddle.

Comment: El fragmento de código (snippet) está funcionando de acuerdo a tus necesidades, ¿entonces, cuál es el problema?. Por otra parte: _"Cuando las horas dobles ya sean 9, el resto de horas se iran a las horas triples"_ resulta incompatible con tu primera condición, porque las horas dobles van a ser como máximo 3, quizá te refieras a limitar el total de horas triples.

Comment: Lo lamento, ya vi que no funciona correctamente. :-D

Comment: Me refiero a una suma total, ese dato se va ir guardando en un campo en mi base de datos "horasdobles" al momento de ser "9" ya las horas se irán guardando en las "horastriples"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes realizar los cálculos, en lugar de asignar directamente los valores a los otros campos. Agregué una variable para poder modificar fácilmente el máximo de horas dobles permitidas.

En comentarios incluí cómo debe realizarse el cálculo.

```js
// Definir una variable para poder cambiar el máximo de horas dobles
let maxDobles = 3;
function HorasTD() {
    // Primero define las variables necesarias
    // Por defecto, todas las horas son dobles
    // Se usa parseInt() para asegurar que el valor es un entero
    let dobles = parseInt($("input#horas").val());
    // Triples inicia en cero
    let triples = 0;
    // Si el total de horas es mayor que el máximo permitido
    if(dobles > maxDobles) {
        // Se asigna la diferencia a triples
        triples = dobles - maxDobles;
        // Asignar a dobles el máximo especificado
        dobles = maxDobles;
    }
    // Después de realizar los cálculos, se asignan los valores
    $("#InputDobles").val(dobles);
    $("#InputTriples").val(triples);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="0" class="form-control" name="horas" id="horas" onChange="HorasTD();"/>

<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="InputDobles" id="InputDobles" readonly=""/>

<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="InputTriples" id="InputTriples" readonly=""/>
```

Si quieres que el máximo de horas dobles sea diferente, solo cambia el valor en la variable definida al inicio y listo.

Comment: Gracias esta fue mi solucion :)